# How to receive and display HTML emails with stylesheets?

Tags: css, email, sanitization

When developing a web-based email system, is there a generally accepted correct way to handle style sheets on incoming emails? I am referring to the `<style` tag. Not referring to `@import` or `<link` notation.

These stylesheets have to be restricted to only the element containing the foreign email, or else they will also adjust the content of your own system, which is a big no-no.

I am aware that I should sanitize scripts and stylesheets, which will allow me to prevent `url` background images, or fixed position elements that would cover parts of my system.

I would not want to drop the stylesheet completely, so I see these options

- Convert style sheets to inline styles
- Put the entire foreign email in its own div with an ID, and change the style rules to only affect that div (for example `a,b{color:purple}` would become `#foreign a,#foreign b{color:purple}`)

Are either of these good ideas? Is there an obvious/better way that I am missing? What is common/accepted/robust?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Email doesn't support external style sheets, so all CSS on a html email is in the page style tag, or inline. As it is standard for clients like gmail and yahoo to strip the style tag, and everything else outside the body tags, you could simply do the same. Limiting incoming emails to inline styles will keep all CSS local to those elements. It is pretty much email design 101 to inline the css, so you don't have to worry about your email system being less than what is standard.

Web clients also strip many CSS elements in addition to this. Don't want someone adding `position:fixed;` for example as it would break out of the viewing pane. The best reference for what CSS is allowed in each client is [Campaign Monitor's CSS guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea is use inline styles. I have made may web sites that send styled html email and inline styles is the only thing tha work in most email sistemas.

Comment: You are missing the point. I agree that I would recommend a sender use inline styles. My question is about the receiving end.